# Why didn't Lucifer bring back Ruby?

Tags: supernatural

So after Lucifer got out, I'm wondering why hasn't he bought Ruby back, since she is THE MAIN REASON for his freedom.

Comment: wasn't Ruby killed with the dagger? AFAIK that means she's dead-for-good dead.

Comment: Because Lucifer hates demons just as much as he hates humans.

Answer (score 3):

In the last episode of season 4 Ruby was killed using the demon-killing-knife, also known as "Ruby's knife".  It is stated in the show that this knife has the ability to kill demons, not just exercise them to hell. Therefore, she can not be brought back.

Her entry on the Supernatural wiki also states that she is deceased.

Edit: In the latest seasons the concept of "The Empty" has been introduced into the mythology of supernatural.  It is still unclear if demons killed by the demon knife or the colt are sent here.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Where does it state this?